# interpolate pandas dataframe with different 'x' spacing

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I would like to fill the NaNs values in dataframe row by row, take for example, the bond rates:

```
timeperiod  cm01  cm03  cm06  cy01  cy02  cy03  cy05  cy07  cy10  cy20  cy30
1962-01-02   NaN   NaN   NaN  3.22   NaN  3.70  3.88   NaN  4.06  4.07   NaN
1962-01-03   NaN   NaN   NaN  3.24   NaN  3.70  3.87   NaN  4.03  4.07   NaN
1962-01-04   NaN   NaN   NaN  3.24   NaN  3.69  3.86   NaN  3.99  4.06   NaN
1962-01-05   NaN   NaN   NaN  3.26   NaN  3.71  3.89   NaN  4.02  4.07   NaN
1962-01-08   NaN   NaN   NaN  3.31   NaN  3.71  3.91   NaN  4.03  4.08   NaN
```

Note that the column names shows the terms for certain bond, which is not evenly spaced. Hence I cannot use `interpolate` directly. Currently, I am filling these NaNs in following manner:

```
terms = np.array([1/12,3/12,6/12,1,2,3,5,7,10,20,30])
term_col = ['cm01', 'cm03', 'cm06', 'cy01', 'cy02', 'cy03', 'cy05', 'cy07', 'cy10', 'cy20', 'cy30']

for i in rf.index:
    d = (rf.loc[i,term_col]).to_numpy(dtype=float)

    spl = CubicSpline(terms[~np.isnan(d)],d[~np.isnan(d)],extrapolate=True)
    rf.loc[i,term_col] = spl(terms)
```

I would like to know if there is simpler/cleaner ways to do this. I feel like I cannot use apply because it does not allow to return multiple values, and I do not want to use `global`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't evenly spaced and you can't use simple interpolation methods, you might consider filling NaN values in your DataFrame using a custom function that fills them row by row based on the available values in that row. One way to do this is to forward-fill NaN values using the last valid value in the same row, or backward-fill using the next valid value in the same row.

Here's a Python code snippet that demonstrates how you can achieve this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create your DataFrame
data = {
    'timeperiod': ['1962-01-02', '1962-01-03', '1962-01-04', '1962-01-05', '1962-01-08'],
    'cm01': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'cm03': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'cm06': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'cy01': [3.22, 3.24, 3.24, 3.26, 3.31],
    'cy02': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'cy03': [3.7, 3.7, 3.69, 3.71, 3.71],
    'cy05': [3.88, 3.87, 3.86, 3.89, 3.91],
    'cy07': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'cy10': [4.06, 4.03, 3.99, 4.02, 4.03],
    'cy20': [4.07, 4.07, 4.06, 4.07, 4.08],
    'cy30': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Fill NaN values row by row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Forward-fill NaN values
    df.loc[index] = row.fillna(method='ffill')
    # Backward-fill NaN values
    df.loc[index] = row.fillna(method='bfill')

print(df)
```

This code snippet iterates through each row in the DataFrame, first forward-filling the NaN values and then backward-filling any remaining NaN values. This approach takes advantage of the fact that your data is sorted by time, and fills each row based on the available values in that row.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, I feel this is not really answering my question, and the wording sounds like GPT style stuff.